# how to use flutter_bloc with go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-navigation

I have built an app where I use flutter_bloc. i want to use go_router for navigation.but for dynamic routing how can i use GoRouter refreshListener parameter with flutter_bloc

```
GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => HomePage.page(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => LoginPage.page(),
    ),
  ],
  redirect: (state) {
    final isLoggedIn =
        bloc.state.status == AuthenticationStatus.authenticated;
    final isLoggingIn = state.location == '/login';

    if (!isLoggingIn && !isLoggingIn) return '/login';
    if (isLoggedIn && isLoggingIn) return "/";

    return null;
  },
  refreshListenable: 
   );
```

Comment: For those that are still looking for a solution, I shared mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77130673/1527008).

Answer (score 9):

Since bloc also returns states in form of a stream, you can directly use it.
You can do it like ->

```
refreshListenable = GoRouterRefreshStream(authenticationBloc.stream),
```

Comment: really nice find...

Comment: How to use this

Comment: This has been removed in GoRouter v5. Refer to the migration guide: https://flutter.dev/go/go-router-v5-breaking-changes

Answer (score 7):

For me, Mixing changeNotifier with the Bloc class and calling notififyListener() from the event worked

This is my bloc class

```
class AuthenticationBloc extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState>
    with ChangeNotifier {
  AuthenticationBloc(
      {required AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository})
      : _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
        super(const AuthenticationState.unknown()) {
    on<AppStarted>(_onAppStarted);

    on<AuthenticationUserChanged>(_onAuthenticationUserChanged);

    on<AuthenticationLogoutRequested>(_onAuthenticationLogoutRequested);

    _userSubscription = _authenticationRepository.user
        .listen((user) => add(AuthenticationUserChanged(user)));
  }

  final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;

  late StreamSubscription<User> _userSubscription;


  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _userSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }


  FutureOr<void> _onAppStarted(
      AppStarted event, Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) {
    emit(AuthenticationState.unknown());
  }

  FutureOr<void> _onAuthenticationUserChanged(
      AuthenticationUserChanged event, Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) {
    final status = event.user != User.empty
        ? AuthenticationState.authenticated(event.user)
        : const AuthenticationState.unauthenticated();
    emit(status);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  FutureOr<void> _onAuthenticationLogoutRequested(
      AuthenticationLogoutRequested event, Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) {
    unawaited(_authenticationRepository.logOut());
  }
}
```

This is GoRouter

```
GoRouter routes(AuthenticationBloc bloc) {
  return GoRouter(
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          name: 'home',
          builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/login',
          name: 'login',
          builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
        ),
      ],
      redirect: (state) {
        final isLoggedIn =
            bloc.state.status == AuthenticationStatus.authenticated;
        final isLoggingIn = state.location == '/login';
        print(isLoggedIn);

        if (!isLoggedIn && !isLoggingIn) return '/login';
        if (isLoggedIn && isLoggingIn) return '/';

        return null;
      },
      refreshListenable: bloc);
}
```

Comment: A not stable approach to use an if-else statement inside the router, you can create a proxy Widget and handle this logic here

Answer (score 2):

After much reading, I want to share my solution, I hope it can help many people. :)

1. I create a file called **go_router_refresh_stream.dart** within my project that looks like this:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class GoRouterRefreshStream extends ChangeNotifier {
  GoRouterRefreshStream(Stream<dynamic> stream) {
    notifyListeners();
    _subscription = stream.asBroadcastStream().listen(
          (dynamic _) => notifyListeners(),
    );
  }

  late final StreamSubscription<dynamic> _subscription;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

2. With the help of getIt, I make a registerLazySingleton of my **AuthBloc**.

```
getIt.registerLazySingleton(
    () => AuthBloc(
      authStatusChangesFirebaseUseCase: getIt(),
      authCurrentUserUseCase: getIt(),
    ),
  );
```

3. I have a mixin of my GoRoute() class and with the help of getIt, I access the stream **property** of my **AuthBloc**.

Mixin GoRoute():

```
mixin RouterMixin on State<MyApp> {
  final _router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: LoginScreen.path,
    errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorScreen(routerState: state),
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: LoginScreen.name,
        path: LoginScreen.path,
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: HomeScreen.path,
        name: HomeScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => HomeScreen(),
      ),
    ],
    redirect: (context, state) async {
      final sessionStatus = context.read<AuthBloc>().state.status;
      if (sessionStatus == AuthStatus.unauthenticated) {
        return LoginScreen.path;
      }
      return null;
    },
    refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(GetIt.instance<AuthBloc>().stream),
  );

  GoRouter get router => _router;
}
```

4. Lastly, I convert my **MyApp** class into a StatefulWidget so that I can use the mixin and also instantiate my BlocProvider:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with RouterMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => getIt<AuthBloc>(),
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        title: 'Dase BackOffice',
        theme: DaseTheme.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: DaseTheme.darkTheme,
        themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
        routerConfig: router,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The route protection works perfectly. The use of getIt with flutter_bloc is completely a personal preference.

pd: I don't publish the logic of my AuthBloc for practical reasons, but if you're interested, I can tell you that it's a copy of the example called Firebase Login found in the official flutter_bloc documentation :P

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
class AuthStateNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  late final StreamSubscription<AuthState> _blocStream;
  AuthStateProvider(AuthBloc bloc) {
    _blocStream = bloc.stream.listen((event) {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _blocStream.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The code is from [this answer](https://github.com/csells/go_router/discussions/122), hope you get the idea.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I found it easier to mixin changenotifier with bloc class and notifylistener() for the particular event, in this case change in authstate

Comment: `minxin` solution sounds easier :)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to return a Streambuilder from my GoRoute and redirect based on the value in the state. refreshListenable also works but you need to pass the bloc inside the router due to which you loose the ability to hot reload on a page as it will refresh the router every time.

```
routes: <GoRoute>[
   GoRoute(
      path: AppPage.login.toPath,
      name: AppPage.login.toName,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: context.read<LoginBloc>().stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print("Updated loginbloc");
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data?.status == LoginStatus.success) {
                return const HomePage();
              } else {
                return const LoginPage();
              }
            }
            return const LoginPage();
          },
        );
      },
    )]
```

Just for context also adding my LoginBloc

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import '../../../services/auth_service.dart';

part 'login_event.dart';
part 'login_state.dart';

class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  LoginBloc({
    required AuthService authService,
  })  : _authService = authService,
        super(const LoginState()) {
    on<LoginButtonPressedEvent>(_handleLoginWithEmailAndPasswordEvent);
    on<LoginEmailChangedEvent>(_handleLoginEmailChangedEvent);
    on<LoginPasswordChangedEvent>(_handleLoginPasswordChangedEvent);
  }

  final AuthService _authService;

  Future<void> _handleLoginEmailChangedEvent(
    LoginEmailChangedEvent event,
    Emitter<LoginState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(email: event.email));
  }

  Future<void> _handleLoginPasswordChangedEvent(
    LoginPasswordChangedEvent event,
    Emitter<LoginState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(password: event.password));
  }

  Future<void> _handleLoginWithEmailAndPasswordEvent(
    LoginButtonPressedEvent event,
    Emitter<LoginState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
      final userLoggedIn = await AuthService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: state.email,
        password: state.password,
      );
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(userLoggedIn);
      }
      if (userLoggedIn != null) {
        emit(state.copyWith(message: 'Success', status: LoginStatus.success));
      } else {
        emit(state.copyWith(message: 'Failure', status: LoginStatus.failure));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(state.copyWith(message: e.toString(), status: LoginStatus.failure));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [example](https://github.com/csells/go_router/blob/main/go_router/example/lib/router_stream_refresh.dart), go_router [supports](https://gorouter.dev/redirection#refreshing-with-a-stream) since a recent release refreshing with a Stream, this would avoid additional wrapping in your code.

Comment: Not supported anymore since GoRouter v5.

Answer (score 0):

Since go_router become an official flutter package the source moved to [here](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/main/packages/go_router). The examples got also updated and [this one](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/async_redirection.dart) should be the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert a Flutter `BLoC`into a Listenable object by using the `ChangeNotifier` class from the Flutter framework.

Here's how you can do it:

```
class BlocListenable<T> extends ChangeNotifier implements Listenable {
  final BlocBase<T> bloc;

  BlocListenable(this.bloc) {
    bloc.stream.listen((state) {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    bloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Use the `listenableBloc` in your router:

```
GoRouter route(AuthenticationBloc bloc) => GoRouter(
        routes: [
        ....
        ],
        redirect: (context, state) {
          final status = bloc.state.status;
          .....
        },
        refreshListenable: BlocListenable(bloc),
      );
```

Now, whenever the state of your BLoC changes, the redirection will notify.

Answer (score 0):

my approach was on redirect use

```
refreshListenable :GoRouterRefreshStream(authenticationBloc.stream),
```

Or with getit

```
  refreshListenable:
        GoRouterRefreshStream(getIt<AuthenticationBloc>().stream),
```

On redirect do not use if on that way because u can't check data inside states

```
     redirect: (state) {
        final bloc = getIt<AuthenticationBloc>().state;
       
        final isLoggingIn = state.location == '/login';
    
        if (bloc is authenticated && !isLoggingIn) return '/login';
        if (bloc is otherState (notAuthenticaded && isLoggingIn) return 
        "/";
    
        return null;
      },
```