# How to handle authentication in Flutter with go_router and Firebase Authentication when already on a route?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router, gorouter

In my Flutter application, I'm using the `go_router` package to manage routes and `Firebase Authentication` for user authentication. I have several screens that require users to be authenticated to access, such as account management, transactions, and details.

Currently, I have implemented redirects with `go_router` to ensure that unauthenticated users are redirected correctly. However, I face a challenge when the user is already on one of these screens and logs out or the session expires.

I'm considering using a BlocListener to detect changes in the authentication state on each screen, but this seems to lead to code duplication. I also have a Stream that notifies changes in the authentication state, thanks to Firebase Authentication, and updates the `contex.isUserSignIn` variable.

What would be the best practice for handling logout or session expiration events in Flutter with go_router and Firebase Authentication efficiently?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I’ve been struggling with the exact same question and have researched several alternatives and options.

**TL;DR:**  Option 3 is my preferred choice, which uses the `GoRouter.refresh()` method at the `main()` level to dynamically update the GoRouter state based on events from the auth stream.

#### Option 1: Follow the go_router async_redirection.dart example

See here for the example: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/async_redirection.dart

This wraps the top level app, typically `MyApp` (as returned by `main()` in `runApp()` ) in an InheritedNotifer widget, which they call `StreamAuthScope` and which creates a dependency between the notifier `StreamAuthNotifier` and go_router's parsing pipeline. This in turn will rebuild `MyApp` (or `App` in the example) when the auth status changes (as communicated by `StreamAuthNotifier` via `notifyListeners()`).

I implemented a similar model based on the Provider package where the `ChangeProviderNotifier` replaces `StreamAuthScope` and wraps the top level `MyApp` returned by `main()`. However this doesn’t allow the creation of a monitored `Provider.of<>` inside the `GoRouter( redirect: )` enclosure. To solve this I created a `getRouter` function that passed in `isUserSignIn` which was monitored with a `Provider.of<>` in the main body of `MyApp` but before the `build` function.  This works but feels cumbersome and
causes the main `MyApp` to be rebuilt each time auth status changes.  If desired, I’m sure you could do something similar with a BLoC model in place of Provider.

#### Option 2: Use `GoRouter`’s `refreshListenable:` parameter

This is based on this go_router redirection.dart example: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/redirection.dart

In the question you mentioned you have a stream that notifies auth state changes.  You can wrap this in a class with `extends ChangeNotifier` to make it Listenable. Then in the constructor you can instantiate and monitor the stream with `.listen`, and in the enclosure issue a `notifyListerners()` each time there is an auth state change (probably each time there is a stream event).  In my case I called this class `AuthNotifier` This can then be used as the listenable with `GoRouter`’s `refreshListenable:` parameter simply as: `refreshListenable: AuthNotifier()`

Example `AuthNotifier` class

```
class AuthNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  AuthNotifier() {
    // Continuously monitor for authStateChanges
    // per: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#authstatechanges
    _subscription =
        FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
          // if user != null there is a user logged in, however
          // we can just monitor for auth state change and notify
          notifyListeners();
        });
  } // End AuthNotifier constructor

  late final StreamSubscription<dynamic> _subscription;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Note: to avoid multiple streams being created and monitored, you need to ensure this constructor is only called once in your app (in this case as part of `GoRouter`’s `refreshListenable:`), or else modify it to be a singleton.

#### Option 3: Use `GoRouter`’s `.refresh()` method

A similar, but more direct approach to option 2 is to use `GoRouter`’s `.refresh()` method. This directly calls an internal `notifyListerners()` that refreshes the GoRouter configuration.  We can use a similar class to the `AuthNotifier` above but we don’t need `extends ChangeNotifier` and would call `router.refresh()` in place of `notifyListeners()`, where `router` is your `GoRouter()` configuration. This new class would be instantiated in `main()`.

Given its so simple (2-3 lines of code), we can also skip the class definition and instantiation and implement the functionality directly in the `main()` body, as follows:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  // Listen for Auth changes and .refresh the GoRouter [router]
  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
    router.refresh();
  });

  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}
```

Since this appears to be the most direct and simplest solution, it is my preferred solution and the one I have implemented.  However there is a lot of confusing and dated information out there and I don’t feel I have enough experience to claim it as any sort of 'best practice', so will leave that for others to judge and comment.

I hope all this helps you and others as it’s taken me a long time with work out these various options and wade through the wide range of materials and options out there.  I feel there is a definitely an opportunity to improve the official go_router documentation in this area !

Comment: Very nice contribution! Helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on Arik_E's answer, here is my implementation:

My main.dart file:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  // Listen for Auth changes and .refresh the GoRouter [router]
  GoRouter router = RoutingService().router;
  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
    router.refresh();
  });

  runApp(App(router: router));
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key, required this.router});
  final GoRouter router;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: router,
      );
}
```

And I have a class which contains my router:

```
class RoutingService {
  final router = GoRouter(
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: MainMenuPage.route,
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
            const MainMenuPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: LoginPage.route,
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
            const LoginPage(),
      ),
    ],

    // redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in
    redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) async {
      final bool loggedIn = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null;
      final bool loggingIn = state.matchedLocation == LoginPage.route;
      if (!loggedIn) return LoginPage.route;
      if (loggingIn) return MainMenuPage.route;
      // no need to redirect at all
      return null;
    },
  );
}
```

In my MainMenuPage and LoginPage, I have the route defined so I can reuse it. Just add `static const route = '/yourRouteName'` to the widget.