How to prevent navigate by url in flutter web
I currently build a flutter web then i show the url which create by Go_router.
basicly like : Login-> save id user -> checl id!= null -> do navigate
How to do it? I have search and try redict but it seem not worl for me, and how to declare in main.dart file
here is the route
GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: MyPath.home,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
        path: MyPath.home,
        builder: (context, state) => const MyHomePage(),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
              path: 'Login', builder: (context, state) => const UserLogin()),
          GoRoute(
              path: 'Register',
              builder: (context, state) => const UserRegister()),
          GoRoute(
              path: 'ForgotPassword',
              builder: (context, state) => const UserForgotPassword()),
        ]),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/Transaction',
      builder: (context, state) {
        return const TransactionSelector();
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
            path: 'ChangePassword',
            builder: (context, state) => const UserChangePassword()),
        GoRoute(
            path: 'ListPhieuHaVo',
            builder: (context, state) =>
                const PhieuDangKyHaVoRequestListScreen()),
        GoRoute(
            path: 'HoaDonDichVuBanRa',
            builder: (context, state) =>
                const HoaDonHangHoaDichVuBanRaRequestListScreen()),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

myNavigate(BuildContext context, String location) {
  if (IDDanhMucDoiTuongThanhToan != '') {
    log(IDDanhMucDoiTuongThanhToan);
    context.go(location);
    return;
  } else if (IDDanhMucDoiTuongThanhToan == '' &&
      location.contains(MyPath.transaction)) {
    log('chưa đăng nhập');
    context.go(MyPath.home);
  }
}

and my main.dart file like this :
MaterialApp.router(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, useMaterial3: false),
      routerConfig: router,
      localizationsDelegates: const [GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }


https://stackoverflow.com/a/78056314/21590733
